# Matching arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, match, recursion

I need check whether a given array will match another array. I can't figure out how to either manipulate the first array, or to match it some other way.

I need to match this array:

```
    Array
(
    [1] => site
    [2] => blog
    [3] => index.php
)
```

to match this:

```
Array
(
    [site] => Array
        (
            [path] => site
            [name] => site
            [kind] => directory
            [content] => Array
                (
                    [404] => Array
                        (
                            [path] => site/404.php
                            [name] => 404.php
                            [extension] => php
                            [kind] => file
                        )

                    [blog] => Array
                        (
                            [path] => site/blog
                            [name] => blog
                            [kind] => directory
                            [content] => Array
                                (
                                    [contact] => Array
                                        (
                                            [path] => site/blog/contact.php
                                            [name] => contact.php
                                            [extension] => php
                                            [kind] => file
                                        )

                                    [index] => Array
                                        (
                                            [path] => site/blog/index.php
                                            [name] => index.php
                                            [extension] => php
                                            [kind] => file
                                        )

                                    [about] => Array
                                        (
                                            [path] => site/blog/about.php
                                            [name] => about.php
                                            [extension] => php
                                            [kind] => file
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [index] => Array
                        (
                            [path] => site/index.php
                            [name] => index.php
                            [extension] => php
                            [kind] => file
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And return the file's content array:

```
                            [index] => Array
                                (
                                    [path] => site/blog/index.php
                                    [name] => index.php
                                    [extension] => php
                                    [kind] => file
                                )
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just index into the array:

```
$b[$a[1]]['content'][$a[2]]['content'][str_replace('.php', '', $a[3])]
```

If your input can be variable length, do this in a loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

So you need...

```
$array2[$array[1]][content][$array[2]][substr(0, stripos($array[3], "."), $array[3])]
```

Or something close...

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = array('site', 'blog', 'index.php');
$node = array(...);  // the tree

for ($i = 0; $i < count($path) && !is_null($node); ++$i) {
  $p = $path[$i];
  $items = $i ? $node['content'] : $node;
  $n = null;
  foreach ($items as $it) {
    if ($it['name'] == $p) {
      $n = $node['content'][$p];
      break;
    }
  }
  $node = $n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I take that to mean you want to check for that list of indexes in the larger array and return any results that are available/matching?  If so, and assuming your first array is called `$indexes` and your second is called `$results` you could do:

```
$found = array();
foreach($indexes as $index) {
  if(isset($results[$index])) {
    $found[] = $results[$index]['content'];
  }
}
```

and now you'd have `$found` with a list of all of the content entries found in $results that matched indexes in $indexes.  Hope that helps.